# Default size and alignment for images (also inserted via html)

Tags: ckeditor

I'd like to know how do I make my `<img>` which I append using `editor.data.set()` to be in a specific size and alignment? Can I define a global size for such appended images? I want it also to work with a normal image adding feature.

I cannot set the default style options for images - `side` / `alignRight` / `alignBlockRight` in my case (I don't know what's the difference between them, but nevermind).

Even if a specific alignment option is active / highlighted, the image is not aligned to the right.

```
        image: {
            styles: {
                options: [
                    'alignLeft', 'alignRight',
                    'alignCenter', 'alignBlockLeft', 'alignBlockRight',
                    'block',
                    {
                        name: 'inline',
                        isDefault: false,
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'side',
                        isDefault: true,
                    },
                ],
            },
```

I tried many ways but nothing works.

My full config:

```
ClassicEditor
    .create(editorElement, {
        plugins: [
            Autoformat,
            Base64UploadAdapter,
            BlockQuote,
            Bold,
            Essentials,
            Heading,
            Image,
            ImageBlockEditing,
            ImageCaption,
            ImageInlineEditing,
            ImageResize,
            ImageStyle,
            ImageToolbar,
            ImageUpload,
            Italic,
            Link,
            List,
            MediaEmbed,
            Paragraph,
            PasteFromOffice,
            SourceEditing,
            Table,
            TableToolbar,
            TextTransformation,
            Underline,
            WordCount,
            GeneralHtmlSupport,
        ],
        toolbar: [
            'heading',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'underline',
            'link',
            'bulletedList',
            'numberedList',
            '|',
            'outdent',
            'indent',
            '|',
            'imageUpload',
            'blockQuote',
            'insertTable',
            'mediaEmbed',
            'undo',
            'redo',
            'sourceEditing',
        ],
        // @ts-expect-error
        htmlSupport: {
            allow: [
                {
                    name: 'img',
                    classes: true,
                    attributes: true,
                }
            ],
        },
        language: 'en',
        image: {
            styles: {
            styles: {
                options: [
                    {
                        name: 'alignRight',
                        isDefault: true,
                    },
                ],
            },
            toolbar: [
                'imageTextAlternative',
                'imageStyle:alignRight',
            ],
        },
        table: {
            contentToolbar: [
                'tableColumn',
                'tableRow',
                'mergeTableCells'
            ]
        }
    })
    .then(ckeditor => {
        editor = ckeditor;

        // editor.execute('imageStyle', { value: 'alignRight' });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

[image]